# hbase put/get works, but not scan, thru hbase java client

Tags: hbase

I'm using hbase-0.98.8-hadoop2 and hadoop-2.7.3 on ubuntu 16.04, in pseudo-distributed mode in a single box.

hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/xxx/hbase-0.98.8-hadoop2/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

When I do 'hbase shell' in command line, everything is good. I can create, put, get, and scan.

But when I use a java client, I'm able to put and get. I can *not* scan. When I try to scan a table, the HRegionServer process quits, without any obvious error. I also turned on DEBUG for org.apache.hadoop.ipc, and still don't see any obvious error. HMaster is still running.

The main java code is the following.

```
Scan scan1 = new Scan();
ResultScanner scanner1 = table.getScanner(scan1);
for (Result res : scanner1) { // the problem happens at scanner1.next()
  System.out.println(res);
}
```

Anyone can shed some light? Thanks.

Comment: can you print what you get when running the code

Comment: In console, I got the following.

Comment: log4j:WARN...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to get result within timeout, timeout=60000ms
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:97)
 at HBaseClient.main(HBaseClient.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to get result within timeout, timeout=60000ms
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:206)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:60)
...

Comment: The region server log has 
INFO [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment... INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain$MyWatcher@2669b199
INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session

Comment: I found the problem. I didn't set the cache. After I do scan.setCaching(). It starts to work. The default caching size turns out to be max int.